# applying SSL Certificate to a site in IIS using C#

Tags: c#, ssl, iis, iis-7

I'm using a tool called certifyTheWeb to apply SSL certificates to the sites I'm having.

I'm looking for a way or another tool that I can use C# to apply SSL certificate to a specific site in my sites list in IIS

any ideas or thought?

Note: I found solutions in Stackoverflow, and i did a research before asking, but I need to manage the site's certificate renewals also, exactly like the tool I mentioned but using C#

Thanks

Comment: You just need to combine `Microsoft.Web.Administration` with some HTTP API Win32 function calls. My project Jexus Manager offers most of the knowledge, https://github.com/jexuswebserver/jexusmanager but you have to dig into the code base to learn how.